# "Input string was not in a correct format" for file upload

Tags: asp.net, database, csv, file-upload, importerror

I am trying to import(upload) a .csv file data to my database in asp.net using C#, but got notified that there is an input string that isn't in the correct format. Please help. Thanks!

> Error line: dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;

```
// Upload and save file
    string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/FileUploads/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[11] { new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("NRIC", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Gender", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("BirthYear", typeof(int)),
        new DataColumn("Number", typeof(int)),
        new DataColumn("PostalCode", typeof(int)),
        new DataColumn("CoursesAttended", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Language", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("DateAttended", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("TrainingPlaces", typeof(int)),
        new DataColumn("Remarks", typeof(string)) });

    string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);

    foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            int i = 0;

            foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
            {
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SilverInfocomm"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            // Set database table name
            bulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.FileUploads";
            con.Open();
            bulk.WriteToServer(dt);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error message is self explanatory! In your CSV file, probably you have string value which you are trying to assign in an `int` column of DataTable.

Comment: Have a breakpoint and see, you are getting this issue due to adding string values to the column whose datatype is int.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check .csv file data and datatable are in same order or not.
In columns like BirthYear,Number,PostalCode,TrainingPlaces are int data type if different format data will raise this error.
check before Upload.
Use try catch block to show message.

this type of error message raise when i tried 
    An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

```
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <Family Name> in BirthYear Column.  Expected type is Int32.
```